# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_GET' (T_VARIABLE) in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, get

When I try to load the "id" from the URL it seems like its not working. Any reason why? Thanks for your help in advance!

```
<?php

class Poll{

    private $db;
    private $presidentid = $_GET['id'];

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getPollData(){
        $sql = "SELECT poll_question, yes, no FROM poll WHERE poll_id = $presidentid";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        $pollData = $statement->fetchObject();
        return $pollData;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: in the current form your prepare step is completely useless. you should read again about the use of parameterized queries. As for the actual problem: move th `$_GET` assignment to the constructor.

Comment: `NO` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks.

Comment: @juergend "NO" is a keyword and not a reserved word. Notice there is no `(R)` next to it. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I never noticed the (R). Thanks.

Comment: @juergend You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we do not put variable in a prepared query.

```
$sql = "SELECT poll_question, yes, no FROM poll WHERE poll_id = :id";

$statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(':id', $this->presidentid);
$statement->execute();
```

see : http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Its problem is not in PDO. Issue is in private $presidentid = $_GET['id']; line

Comment: altogether, but once the modification is complete, we also changed the PDO party.

Answer (score 0):

```
private $presidentid = $_GET['id'];
```

Replace above line with bellow line, it will work fine,

```
class Poll{

    private $db;
    private $presidentid;
    public function __construct($db){
            $this->db = $db;
            $this->presidentid = $_GET['id'];
        }
```

I'll explain, why you should not use like  **private $presidentid = $_GET['id'];**
once your problem is solved.

Comment: It just returned "Notice: Undefined variable: presidentid in..."